# What must be considered when modifying Oracle DATE column to TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, date, jdbc, timestamp, database-performance

The system I'm working on uses an oracle 11 db and has a java implemented backend which uses JDBC.

**The system has one main performance problem:**

The oracle db has indexed DATE columns but the java backend access the db like this

```
String sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE a_date > ?";
// ... prepare the statement
statement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp());
```

then Oracle will not use the index and fall back to full table scan because of statement.setTimestamp.

**First Solution:**

So I have changed the access of the backend from *statement.setTimestamp* to *statement.setDate*. 
The performance has been improved and the DATE index was now used, but now I lost the accuracy of the timestamp data type, and only got a day-accuracy of the java.sql.Date type.

*Thus, the first solution was unusable for my system.*

**Second Solution:**

I don’t change the java backend thus using *statement.setTimestamp* and change all DATE columns of the oracle db like the following sql command example:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_1> MODIFY <date_column> TIMESTAMP;
```

**Now my question:**

**What must be considered when modifying Oracle DATE column to TIMESTAMP**

I think a list of the important aspects would be perfect.

Here my first draft of the "CHECKLIST of Migrating Oracle DATE columns to TIMESTAMP

**1. CREATE / INSERT**

**2. READ / SELECT**

**3. UPDATE / UPDATE**

**4. DELETE / DELETE**

**5. TO_DATE( )**

```
select * from table where crea_time between TO_DATE( '10.2014', 'MM.yyyy' ) and TO_DATE( '12.2014', 'MM.yyyy' ) ;
```

**6. TRUNC( )**

```
select TRUNC( crea_time ) from table;
```

output of crea_time data typ DATE
05.11.2014 00:00:00
output of crea_time data typ TIMESTAMP
05.11.2014 00:00:00

**7. TO_CHAR( )**

```
select to_char( crea_time,'hh24miss' ) from table;
```

output data typ DATE
140612
output data typ TIMESTAMP
140612

**8. NESTED - TRUNC( TO_DATE() )**

```
select TRUNC(TO_DATE( crea_time), 'YEAR') from table;
```

output of crea_time data typ DATE
01.01.2014 00:00:00
output of crea_time data typ TIMESTAMP
ORA-01830:
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:
*Action:
Solution >>> select TRUNC( TO_TIMESTAMP( crea_time), 'YEAR' ) from table;
output of crea_time data typ TIMESTAMP
01.01.2014 00:00:00

**9. Add A DAY/HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND**

```
select crea_time+1 from table;
```

output data typ DATE
06.11.2014 14:06:12

output data typ TIMESTAMP
06.11.2014 14:06:12

**10. MIN() / MAX()**

```
SELECT MIN(crea_time) FROM table;
```

output data typ DATE
05.11.2014 14:06:12
output data typ TIMESTAMP
05.11.2014 14:06:12,000000000

*Please excuse my bad English.*